# Convert collection of dictionary into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of dictionary and i would like to convert it to DataFrame columns, where the dictionary keys are the columns of dataframe columns in Python 3.5.

Here is the structure of my current collection:
[image]

I want to convert this to a pandas data frame as follows:

```
Col1   Col2  Col3
2.17   41.1  1
```

Comment: why you don't put it as text?

Comment: If you have a list of dictionaries, you can simply do pandas.DataFrame(extracted['data']) ?

Comment: You appear to have a Series full of dicts, not a list. How did you even get this Series? You should probably change the code that created this thing, rather than post-processing it.

Comment: @treegarden this suggestion does not work. i tried it already.

Comment: Then it's most likely not a list of dicts, as @user2357112 suggested

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem and here is the code that allows you to extract dict elements inside columns of a pandas dataframe.

Here is the original record format:
[image]

```
# Extract message details into a new dataframe
s = pd.Series(extracted['data']).dropna()
cols = ['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4']
rows = []

for idx,i in enumerate(s): 
    row = [i['Col1'],i['Col2'],i['Col3'],i['Col4']]
    rows.append(row)
    
sensors = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = cols)
sensors.head()
```

Output is:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why is the actual answer (column headings) cut off?